# What is the equivalent of Twitter's @reply in Google+?

Tags: google-plus

If someone leaves a comment on my post and I want to reply back to them, how can I make sure they get my reply?  In Twitter you append an [at symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/At_sign) to the front of their name to create an @reply message.  Is there an equivalent in Google+?  If so, how do I reply to a specific comment?

Comment: Ampersand is "&". "@" is "at". Not sure if it has a better name than that. (Hey, that rhymed!)

Comment: On another note, replying in G+ seems similar: you start with @ and then auto-complete for the names of people who commented should kick in. I've seen it not always work as expected, though, so I'm not going to post this as an answer.

Comment: @Anna: Thanks for the correction, and the answer.  That did work.  I kept looking for any kind of button or link when I should have just tried it.  :)

Comment: Using the `@` should work exactly the same as using `+` as it appears to convert it to `+` anyway.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you start your comment off with a `+` or an `@` it starts to autofill the user's name. So if you wanted to respond to me you would do `+Jorge` or `@Jorge` and then autocomplete.

The person you are responding to then gets a notification in their Plus toolbar thing:

[image]

You can also set [the settings](https://plus.google.com/settings/plus) to enable notification via mail and Phone (though that can get spammy in my experience).

[image]

Comment: Note: `@` also brings up the autocomplete box